# Не применяется картинка в background

Tags: html, css, html5, background, background-image

Не могу применить background. И так и сяк. Бес понятия, что такое. До этого все было ок!

css

```
.intro {
    background: url("../img/main/bg2.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

html

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо задать для класса `intro` ширину и высоту в `100%`, а так же убедиться, что все родительские элементы, в которые вложен данный, так же не имеют ограничения по ширине.

```css
    html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: url('https://s3.tproger.ru/uploads/2016/03/stack_logo2.png') center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не помогло, все также

Comment: @Sevastopol' Тут Вы, конечно, правы. Ну будем надеяться, что это не на долго.

Comment: @Air Учитывая, что мы тут только втроём, предположу что минус от Вас? )))

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я стараюсь не обращать внимания на комментарии последнее время ))) Себе дороже.

Comment: @Air Так он рабочий был. Если себе код скачать, то работало бы ) Это тут `http` не читает. ) Благодарю за честность, это многого стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ли я Вас понял? 
html не трогал,
css:

```
.intro {
    background: url("https://vjoy.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/1-12.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```